# A music catalog service (Spotify, etc), with compact table views and the ability to granularly rate songs

Tags: music

The basic features I'm looking for:

- access to a large catalog of songs
- semi functional meta-data of the songs
- the ability to rate songs (not a binary rating system, but actual ratings like iTunes)
- compact, efficient, table views

I've checked out YouTube Music, iTunes Music, Amazon Music, Spotify, and TIDAL.  Every one of them have non-table based UIs and a lack of ratings, making it extremely difficult to scroll through an artists discography picking out the songs one likes most (5 star), or perhaps just enough (3 star, etc).

In a nut-shell, what I'm looking for is Napster with decent meta-data, modern internet speeds, and cloud storage of my ratings and play-counts.  Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I think I've figured out what to do:  I can use the spotify api / web playback sdk combined with a personal server to create the system I want.

Comment: Interested in your implementation should you come up with one, following.